# Design of cascaded controllers

Tags: c++

I have a control system and I'm doing a triplet cascaded controllers, I have designed an interface like that

```
IController
{
void Run();
IController *pFirstController;
IController *pSecondController;
}
```

My question is for design of triplet cascaded controller, what's the best way in terms of storing a pointer to a third controller, or a make a concrete class implementation of the third cascaded controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish should fit into a [Chain of Responsibility design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility) (also [here](http://www.dofactory.com/net/chain-of-responsibility-design-pattern)).  In this pattern, each handler (controller in this case) knows only the next controller (but it doesn't know every controller in the chain).

Chain of Responsibility is a simple case of [Flow-based programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow-based_programming).

Comment: how would I use a class definition like that ? My concern is how would I use that interface to feedforward the inital PID controller to other controllers ?

Comment: Draw a block diagram for your control system.  From your description, it's not yet clear how you are planning to arrange the feed-back and feed-forward.

Comment: I want to design SIMO and MIMO. So I want a good interface design. but thanks a lot you understood what I want